# Python unittest runs my non test file

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have two files, FinalProject.py and Test_FinalProject.py.

The code for my test class is:

```
import unittest
import FinalProject

class TestFinalProject(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_read_dataset(self):
        dsm = FinalProject.DatasetManager()
        dsm.read_dataset()
        self.assertEqual(len(dsm.list_potatoes), 6480)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Every time I run this from within PyCharm or cmd, my FinalProject.py code runs instead, no matter what changes I make. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Edit: Code from FinalProject.py

```
class DatasetManager():

    def __init__(self):
        self.list_potatoes = []
        self.sorted_list_potatoes = []

    def read_dataset(self):
        try:
            with open('00010014-eng.csv') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
                self.list_potatoes = list(reader)
            csvfile.close()
        except IOError:
            print("Could not read file.")

    def get_record_count(self):
        return len(self.list_potatoes)
```

Comment: Could you show your PyCharm run configuration for the tests? How do you run your tests?

Comment: Also, what is inside `FinalProject.py`?

Comment: @alecxe I'm new to python and PyCharm, how would I show the run configuration? I just run the file. In cmd I tried "python Test_FinalProject.py" and that didn't work either.

Comment: what is '__init__' function in FinalProject.py ?

Comment: @m0z4rt     def __init__(self):
        
        self.list_potatoes = []
        self.sorted_list_potatoes = []

Comment: Could you add the code of FinalProject ?, maybe list_potatoes always return fix size.

Comment: @alecxe I added the relevant code from FinalProject.py

Comment: @m0z4rt I added the relevant code from FinalProject.py

Comment: Your main script does not even have a "starter", it only defined a class and exits. Your test on the other side creates an instance of the class and calls a method which obviously runs the code. What else did you expect?

Comment: @KlausD. that class doesn't have the main in it, just the functions, the main class is RunProgram where I have def main(self): my functions and loop and is run by calling RunProgram().main() at the end

Comment: You should post *all* relevant code and make full clear what you do, expect to happen and observe instead!

Answer (score 0):

let's try this:

```
class DatasetManager():

    def __init__(self):
        self.list_potatoes = []
        self.sorted_list_potatoes = []

    def read_dataset(self):
        try:
            with open('00010014-eng.csv') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
                self.list_potatoes += list(reader)
        except IOError:
            print("Could not read file.")

    def get_record_count(self):
        return len(self.list_potatoes)
```

Comment: I tried it but the main method from my FinalProject.py still gets ran instead

Comment: what is main method ? you mean "read_dataset" ?, sure it run firstly.

Comment: I made the edit. In the FinalProject.py file I made another class for running the functions in the DatabseManager class, that class runs instead of unit testing.

Comment: how do you run test ? Could you put unitest to other file (ex: test_unit.py) and run : python test_unit.py

Comment: I have tried new files and nothing changed. I run it on cmd mainly. I never see the unittest interface with the "x tests run in x seconds"